# Storing a database reference within the database

Tags: sql, database, linux, postgresql, debian

I want to be able to label the database with a single value, i.e its name, from within the database instead of my application, since it will always be one ID per database. For example, something like this:

**DATABASE_A.sql**

```
-- Database Name Table
CREATE TABLE database (
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE item (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

Insert Into database (name) values ('A');
```

**DATABASE_B.sql**

```
-- Database Name Table
CREATE TABLE database (
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE item (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

Insert Into database (name) values ('B');
```

This is because when they are combined and stored on a SOLR search server their ID is a combination of their database name and their item ID, such as this:

**SOLR ITEM ID's**

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
```

Is it ok to have a single table to define the prefix so that when I do the look up from my SQL website to SOLR I can just do the following query:

```
database (name) + item (id) = SolrID
```

Comment: From where is SOLR obtaining the database name?

Comment: It has something called a dataimporthandler which queries my database and imports it into solr

Comment: It would query the database(name) table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be more inclined to build a procedure in each database that contained the database ID, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION solrid(IN local_id INTEGER, OUT result TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE
  database_id TEXT := 'A';
BEGIN
  result := database_id || local_id::TEXT;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Then you could write your select statement like:

```
SELECT solrid(id), name FROM item;
```

which seems to be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Just to get my head around this, this is basically creating a function where I can query solrid, but I dont have to actually store it as a value in the database, it gets created on the fly but adding the ID to my database_id TEXT

Comment: solrid is a function.  You pass it an integer ID and it generates a Solr-style ID by prepending the database ID and converting the ID to text.  You would put this function in each database, changing the database_id so that it contains the database's unique identifier.